# showing build config in status bar visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, statusbar

I don´t use the dropdown menus on the toolbars so I have removed all of them but the buildconfig state is not shown any other way which is annoying. So I am thinking of writing something for the statusbar. But I thought maybe someone else have done that? Anyone out there with a fix?

I have found this: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/net/new-features-for-the-statusbar-in-mfc/ so I guess I can write my own but rather not spend time on it if someone else done it already.